# Show a react-placeholder skeleton until a image loaded completely in a page

Tags: reactjs

I'm Beginner in react, i want to show a skeleton placeholder until a image loads completely in my page so I used `react-placeholder` library for skeleton loader and set the `loaded` state to `false` so the skeleton loader shows.
I then change the loaded to true by setState it on onLoad function on `img` tag but my problem is the state is not changing so the skeleton loader shows infinitely thus hiding the image.

how to fix this? what i done wrong here? Someone please help me solve this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactPlaceholder from 'react-placeholder';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    }
  }
  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <React.Fragment>
      <ReactPlaceholder type = 'rect' ready = {this.state.loaded} style = {{height: 160}} >
        <div className = "imageHolder" >
          <img src ="http://someImage.png" alt = "" onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)} />
        </div> 
      </ReactPlaceholder> 
    
    </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The component inside <ReactPlaceholder/> will not render unless the state is true. onLoad function inside img is not being called since it is inside <ReactPlaceholder/> and state is false.

Comment: @Suniltc, now i can understand, but can you provide me a way to solve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"react-placeholder" is not rendering the image until `state.loaded` is true, so the `onLoad` callback will never be executed.

You should take the control of rendering the placeholder and control the image visibility by yourself, and do not use the "react-placeholder" component as it requires a children node, which is not the best election for this case.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ImagePlaceholder from "./ImagePlaceholder";

class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    }
  }

  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { loaded } = this.state;
    const imageStyle = !loaded ? { display: "none" } : {};
    return ( 
      <div className = "imageHolder" >
        {!loaded && <ImagePlaceholder/> }
        <img src ="http://someImage.png" style={imageStyle} onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Anyway, if you still want to continue using "react-placeholder", then you could solve it with something like:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactPlaceholder from "react-placeholder";

class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false
    }
  }

  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { loaded } = this.state;
    const imageStyle = !loaded ? { display: "none" } : {};
    const image = <img src="http://someImage.png" style={imageStyle} onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)} />;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ReactPlaceholder type="rect" ready={this.state.loaded} style={{height: 160}} >
          <div className="imageHolder" >
            {image}
          </div> 
        </ReactPlaceholder>
        {!loaded && image}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @javier, is there anything way to not repeating the image tag twice?

Comment: Of course, as I told, the example was not optimized and it was intended to be used only as a brief explanation of how you could solve the problem. I will edit it now to show you how.

Comment: Thanks @Javier, Now i can understand and your solution working awesomely

Comment: Thanks so much! This works pretty good for me!