# How to show placeholder image if image link dosn't exist react-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am using links to show images. If a user gives an invalid image link that doesn't exist or can't be accessed how can I show a placeholder image?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question so that someone can know how to direct you better?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59208137/12541413 ?